# Metodo para Guardar multiples checkbox e input con json y luego mostrar

Tags: php, json, mysqli

[image: estructura tabla]Estoy haciendo mi proyecto para graduarme, es una web admin de obras y estoy buscando como insertar en la tabla OBRAS los materiales con las cantidades `(obras_cant)` y las herramientas con sus cantidades `(herra_cant)` , ejemplo: Pintura gris-15 Gal, arena m2, esmeril 2 Unds. En este caso "pintura gris" ya lo traigo desde la tabla `materiales`, al igual que "esmeril" de la tabla `herramientas`de  para luego mostrar las obras en listas con sus materiales y herramientas en pdf para ser checkeadas a la hora de ser entregadas. un profesor que era mejor hacerlo colocando el campo LONGTEXT e insertar todo con JSON para que guarde el `id` de cada herramienta o material con sus cantidades respectivamente. pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo. hasta ahora estoy mostrando los datos consultar para seleccionar con checkbox......

```
<?php include_once 'templates/header-internas.php';
require_once('funciones/bd_conexion.php');
?>
<section class="seccion contenedor">
<h2>Agregar Obra</h2>

<form action="validar_obras.php" class="login"  method="POST" id="obras">
    <div class="campo">
        <label for="obra">Nombre: </label>
            <input type="text" name="obra" id="obra" placeholder="Introducir obra">
    </div>
    <div class="campo">
        <label for="compra">Numero de Orden compra: </label>
            <input type="text" name="compra" id="compra" placeholder="Introducir">
    </div>
    <div class="campo">
      <label for="user">Supervisor a Cargo:</label>
        <?php
          try {

            $sql = "SELECT *  FROM usuarios WHERE status_id = 3 ";
            $res_user = $conn->query($sql);
            echo "<select name='user'>";
            while ($user = $res_user->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $user['id_user'] ?> ">
                <?php echo $user['nombre_user'] . " " . $user['apellido_user']; ?>
              </option>
          <?php }
            echo "</select>";
          } catch (Exception $error) {
            echo "Error:" . $error->getMessage();
          }
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="campo clearfix">
      <label for="client">Cliente </label>
        <?php
          try {

            $sql = "SELECT *  FROM clientes ";
            $res_client = $conn->query($sql);
            echo "<select name='client'>";
            while ($client = $res_client->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $client['id'] ?> ">
                <?php echo $client['nom_cliente'] . " " . $client['planta']; ?>
              </option>
          <?php }
            echo "</select>";
          } catch (Exception $error) {
            echo "Error:" . $error->getMessage();
          }
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="campo clearfix">
      <label for="herram">Selecionar herramientas:</label><br/>
        <?php
          try {

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM herramienta ";
            $res_herram = $conn->query($sql);
            while ($herram = $res_herram->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="herram[]"  value=' . $herram['id_herra'] . '> ' . $herram['nom_herra'] . " " ;
            echo '<input type="number" min="0" max="5" id="cant_herram" size="1" name="herram_cant" placeholder="0">' . '<br/>';
            }
          } catch (Exception $error) {
            echo "Error:" . $error->getMessage();
          }
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="campo desplegable clearfix">
      <label for="mater">Selecionar materiales:</label><br/>
        <?php
          try {

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM materiales ";
            $res_mater = $conn->query($sql);
            while ($mater = $res_mater->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '<label><input type="checkbox" name="mater[]"  value=' . $mater['id_mat'] . '> ' . $mater['nom_mat'] . " " ;
            echo '<input type="number" min="0" max="50" id="cant_mat" size="1" name="mat_cant[]" placeholder="0">' . '<br/>';
            }
          } catch (Exception $error) {
            echo "Error:" . $error->getMessage();
          }
        ?>
    </div>

    <div class="campo">
            <input type="submit" id="agregar" name="submit" class="button" value="Agregar">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Podrías agregar la estructura de la tabla para poder facilitar el ayudarte, así mismo veo que existe una redundancia en antes de cada consulta MySQLi utilizas la función `requiere_once()` y "mandas a llamar" al mismo archivo, esto es innecesario, basta con solo realizarlo una vez.

Comment: @alexchvrches gracias por escribir, el `require` lo colocare al inicio, mantendre en `close_con` al final. y  ya  subi la imagen de la tabla,  amigo

Comment: @alexchvrches ya tengo solucion para la insercion de los datos y tambien para mostrarlos pero la pagina no me deja publicar la respuesta para documentacion y le sirva a alquien mas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Respuesta movida de [esta publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/125546/un-metodo-para-guardar-multiples-checkbox-e-input-con-json-y-luego-mostrar) a la pregunta original

[image: asi se muestra como realizar la insercion con el codigo al inicio mostrado] ya solucione el dilema y publicare para alguien que quiera hacerlo y se ahorre problemas de creacion de codigo extra o guardar muchas tablas en su DB.
al guardar en la base de datos realize la insercion de las OBRAS y HERRAMIENTAS con sus cantidades mediante la funcion `JSON_ENCODE` llamando las funciones `$herramientas = herramientas_json($herram, $cant_h);
    $materiales = materiales_json($mater, $cant_m);`
troso de codigo donde realizo el llamado a la funciones y posteriormente la insercion a la DB

```
$obra = $_POST['obra'];
$compra = $_POST['compra'];
$user = $_POST['user'];
$client = $_POST['client'];
$herram = $_POST['herram'];
$cant_h = $_POST['herram_cant'];
$mater = $_POST['materi'];
$cant_m = $_POST['mat_cant'];

include_once 'funciones/funciones.php';
$herramientas = herramientas_json($herram, $cant_h);
$materiales = materiales_json($mater, $cant_m);
try {
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO obras (nom_obras, orden_compra, user_id, client_id, mater_cant, herra_cant) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $obra, $compra, $user, $client, $materiales, $herramientas);
$stmt->execute();
```

de alli  va a `funciones.php` la cual realiza la conversion a `Json` tambien de deconversion con `JSON_DECODE`. primmero la conversion

```
<?php
function herramientas_json(&$herram, &$cant_h) {
$total_herramientas = array_combine($herram, $cant_h);
$json = array();
foreach ($total_herramientas  as $key => $cant_h) :
if ((int) $cant_h > 0) :
  $json[$key] = (int) $cant_h;
endif;
endforeach;

return json_encode($json);

}
function materiales_json(&$mater, &$cant_m) {
$total_materiales = array_combine($mater, $cant_m);
$json_m = array();
foreach ($total_materiales  as $key => $cant_m) :
if ((int) $cant_m > 0) :
  $json_m[$key] = (int) $cant_m;
endif;
endforeach;

 return json_encode($json_m);
}
```

despues de realizado el procedimiento de insercion, los datos se guadran de la siguiente manera [image: se muestran los campos de la tabla obra]
observando los campos `mat_cant` y  `herra_cant` se insertan los datos con el formato `json` pero si ven el codigo mas arriba de `materiales_json` utilizo la funcion `array_combine` para unir el `id` de materiales o hemmaientas segun la funcion y guardar un json mas corto.
Luego para mostrar y dar formato a los datos guardados lo hice de la siguiente manera

```
$sql2 = 'SELECT `nom_obras`, `orden_compra`, `mater_cant`, `herra_cant`, `nombre_user`, `apellido_user`, `nom_cliente`, `planta`  FROM obras INNER JOIN usuarios ON usuarios.id_user = obras.user_id INNER JOIN clientes ON clientes.id = obras.client_id ';
$res_obra = $conn->query($sql2);
?>

<div class="contenido existentes">
<h2>Existentes</h2>
<p>
  Obras Agregadas: <?php echo $res_obra->num_rows; ?>
</p>

<table id="obra_registrada">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Nombre Obra</th>
          <th>Orden de Compra</th>
          <th>cliente</th>
          <th>Supervisor</th>
          <th>Materiales</th>
          <th>Herramientas</th>
     <th><button type="button" name="borrar" id="btn_borrar" class="borrar"></button></th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php while($registros1 = $res_obra->fetch_assoc() ) {?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $registros1['nom_obras']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $registros1['orden_compra']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $registros1['nom_cliente']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $registros1['nombre_user'] . " " . $registros1['apellido_user']; ?></td>

            <td><?php $materia = $registros1['mater_cant'];
            $sql2 = formatear_materiales($materia);
            $sql = "SELECT `nom_mat`, `id_mat` FROM materiales WHERE id_mat = 'a' ";
            foreach ($sql2 as $key => $value) {
            $sql .= " OR id_mat = '{$key}'";

            $materiales_registrado = $conn->query($sql);
          while($listado = $materiales_registrado->fetch_assoc()) {

            if ($key == $listado['id_mat']) {
              echo $listado['nom_mat'] . ": " . $value . "<br/>";
            }
            }
        }

            ?></td>

            <td><?php $herram = $registros1['herra_cant'];
           $sql2 = formatear_herramientas($herram);
      $sql = "SELECT `nom_herra`, `id_herra` FROM herramienta WHERE id_herra = 'a' ";
            foreach ($sql2 as $key => $value) :
            $sql .= " OR id_herra = '{$key}'";
            $herramientas_registradas = $conn->query($sql);
            while($listado = $herramientas_registradas->fetch_assoc()) {
            if ($key == $listado['id_herra']) :
              echo $listado['nom_herra'] . ": " . $value . "<br/>";
            endif;
            }
          endforeach;
            ?></td>
            <td>
          <a href="editar.php?id=<?php echo $registros2['id_obras']; ?>">
                Editar
                </a>
            </td>
            <td class="borrar">
          <input class="borrar_contacto" type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $registros2['id_obras']; ?>" value="">
            </td>

        </tr>
    <?php }
  } catch (Exception $error) {
  echo "Error:" . $error->getMessage();
    };
     ?>
  </tbody>
  </table>

</div>

<?php

 $conn->close(); ?>
```

Si revisan detenidamente en los `<td>` de materiales y tambien en herramientas se realiza el llamdo a las funciones de `formatear_materiales` y `formatear_herramientas` de alli va a `funciones.php` y realiza el `json_decode`

```
function formatear_materiales($materia) {
$materia = json_decode($materia, true );
return $materia;
}
function formatear_herramientas($herram) {
$herram = json_decode($herram, true );
return $herram;
}
```

ya con eso y los siclos de sql, foreach y while, se realizan las consultas a las tablas materiales y herramientas para mostrar todo como se muestra en la siguiente imagen
[image: tabla de obras agregadas]

espero les sirva de algo, y si me equivoco y pueden mejorar el codigo, POR FAVOR no duden en escribir sus comentarios.